# Is it haram to read about sex just for fun?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, pornography

When I had free time I would love to read, but due to COVID I can't access any 'real' library books, so I just started reading online books. After some time in reading though I started reading characters having sex, I didn't know what it was at first but after some research I started to realize what is it. I try not to read but it's just so addicting, I really am trying to stop because I don't know if it's haram and I want to stop but I just can't. Every time I try blocking that book it comes back into my mind and I read it again. After I read it I feel regret and ask for forgiveness. I always wish I hadn't read it but once again it'll come into my mind and I'll read it and therefore the cycle restarts. I don't know if it's good or bad and I don't know how to stop. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Hadith

وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏

‏كُتب على ابن آدم نصيبه من الزنا مدرك ذلك لا محالة‏:‏ العينان زناهما النظر، والأذنان زناهما الاستماع، واللسان زناه الكلام، واليد زناها البطش، والرجل زناها الخطا، والقلب يهوى ويتمنى، ويصدق ذلك الفرج أو يكذبه‏"

‏‏‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏‏ وهذا لفظ مسلم، ورواية البخاري مختصرة‏)‏‏)‏‏‏

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has written the very portion of Zina which a man will indulge in. There will be no escape from it. The Zina of the eye is the (lustful) look, the Zina of the ears is the listening (to voluptuous songs or talk), the Zina of the tongue is (the licentious) speech, the Zina of the hand is the (lustful) grip, the Zina of the feet is the walking (to the place where he intends to commit Zina), the heart yearns and desires and the private parts approve all that or disapprove it."

[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

This is the wording in Muslim; Al-Bukhari wording is a bit short.

Sunnah.com : Book 18, Hadith 112
Arabic/English book : Book 18, Hadith 1622
Riyad us Saliheen

Never go near this as it can lead you to zina which is an major sin.do act which Allah love e.g prayer fasting
Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدَانُ، عَنْ أَبِي حَمْزَةَ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، عَنْ عَلْقَمَةَ، قَالَ بَيْنَا أَنَا أَمْشِي، مَعَ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ فَقَالَ كُنَّا مَعَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ ‏

‏ مَنِ اسْتَطَاعَ الْبَاءَةَ فَلْيَتَزَوَّجْ، فَإِنَّهُ أَغَضُّ لِلْبَصَرِ وَأَحْصَنُ لِلْفَرْجِ، وَمَنْ لَمْ يَسْتَطِعْ فَعَلَيْهِ بِالصَّوْمِ، فَإِنَّهُ لَهُ وِجَاءٌ ‏"

‏‏‏

Narrated 'Alqama:

While I was walking with `Abdullah he said, "We were in the company of the Prophet (ﷺ) and he said, 'He who can afford to marry should marry, because it will help him refrain from looking at other women, and save his private parts from committing illegal sexual relation; and he who cannot afford to marry is advised to fast, as fasting will diminish his sexual power."

Sahih al-Bukhari 1905
In-book : Book 30, Hadith 15
USC-MSA web (English) : Vol. 3, Book 31, Hadith 129  (deprecated)
Sahih Bukhari

Indulge in dhikr . there are many differnt dhikrs e.g for evening and morning which will rise our level in paradise.

Comment: While reading this hadith, we are still reading about that. isn't it?

Comment: What do u mean??i am sorry but i dont understand ur question.

Comment: Please mark your quotations as such to make them clearly distinguishable from your own words.

Answer (score -1):

AoA,
I have experienced this, and reading sex stories is not explicitly haram, but it is definitely not halaal either.
The best way is to repent for any sins done, and to believe in god and pray for forgiveness with all true intention.
Hope this helped!
-Amber

Comment: please stop spreading lies

Answer (score -1):

In this question, the expression "for fun" is the main criterion. In this case, the question is summarized in لهو and لعب:
(إِنَّمَا الْحَیاةُ الدُّنْیا لَعِبٌ وَ لَهْوٌ 47/36)
The (appearance of) life of the world is just palying and entertainment, while you were believed and Godwory, God will give you reward ... In this verse, God will reward who has Godwary (التقوی).
"لعب" is an action that has a kind of imagination to achieve a fantasy goal, and "لهو" is an entertainment job that is busy and deviate from the main gauls. So keeping a job that is not necessary will weaken faith.

On the other hand, being forbidden is a credit. For a person who is lost in the desert and is very hungry, eating a forbidden animal is also a solvent (albeit to survive). Means that only in certain conditions, forbidden actions could be done; Let's observe "for fun". In whole, whatever weakens faith, reduces man from the degrees of heaven and reduces his place. The less of "for entertainment", is the greater of the faith.